# libGDX : How check if the actor exist on stage or not

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I check the actor is removed or not on stage ?

like this:

```
if(actor.isRemoved) {
   // enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#getStage--):

> getStage
>
> public Stage getStage() Returns the stage that this actor is
> currently in, or null if not in a stage.

So you can use it like:

```
if(actor.getStage() == null) {
    //actor not on stage
}
```