# libGDX: Check if actor exists fails with NullPointerException

Tags: libgdx, actor

I am trying to check if an actor exists but have no luck so far. My code looks like this:

```
if (prize.getStage() == null)
     System.out.println("not on stage");
else
     System.out.println("on stage");
```

According to the answer in this link:
[libGDX : How check if the actor exist on stage or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270598/libgdx-how-check-if-the-actor-exist-on-stage-or-not)

But I receive the following error:
"LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or if there is another good way to check if an actor is on stage?

Comment: I think your prize is null ?

Comment: You are of course correct, clumsy of me :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As Abhishek Aryan suggests, my prize is null. All I had to do was to make sure that prize was initialized. 
Silly of me.